# Can I get the name and age of the person who has "Logged In With PayPal" in my app?

Tags: paypal, authentication

I'm developing a crowdfunding service application, and I want to get the information of the person who wants to be funded with my service.

I'm using PayPal for gathering money from people, and he who takes the money has to complete his project goal.

To prevent cheating and check the age, I have to get some personal information from the project owner and verify them.
I'm wondering if I can get information from PayPal when the project owner logges in to PayPal from my application.

Is there any way I can get the verified name and age from users of my app via PayPal?

Comment: PayPal doesn't know their age AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It's not possible. Your best shot is to include that question in your website by yourself, and hope that the user is honest. They could also lie in the Paypal form anyway. Paypal is definitely not giving personal information away.

Comment: Ok, now I'm wondering if I can demand PayPal the information when the user turned out to be fraudulent?

Comment: If it was fraudulent then the account they logged in with probably wasn't their's anyway.